# Как загрузить картинку в базу данных и отобразить фото в объекте picture?

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, binding

Т.е. как забиндить, чтоб отображалось фото (WPF/ C#).

Answer (score 2):

Изображения в базе данных хранятся как массив байтов, в общем xaml понимает их без конвертации:

```
<Image Name="Picture"
       Source="{Binding}">           
</Image>
```

Однако так это массив байтов, есть нюанс при сохранении в бд рисунка, собственно рисунок надо конвертировать в byte[] как то так:

```
private byte[] set_bitmat(Bitmap bmp)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
         bmp.Save(ms, bmp.RawFormat);
         return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

И уже получившийся результат писать в базу данных

Answer (score 1):

А может просто залить картинку, на какой-нибудь хостинг, а потом в базу вбить только ссылку, после чего надо считать данные из базы и передать из в переменную, а после просто загрузить их в pictureBox

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = Имя переменной
```