# Как вставить картинку в бд ms sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

Вставляю картинку c использованием Entity Framework и TagLib:

```
            if (tagFile.Tag.Pictures.Length > 0) newRowMus.setPicture(tagFile.Tag.Pictures[0]);
```

А затем:

```
            using (var db = new BaseData())
            {
                var Mus = new Music
                {
                    songID = Id,
                    songName = this.Title,
                    songArtist = this.Artist,
                    songAlbum = this.Album,
                    songYear = this.Year,
                    songPicture = this.Picture
                };
                db.Music.Add(Mus);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

БД выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выводит исключение:  String or binary data would be truncated.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понял она просто не влазит, если использовать binary(MAX) - то же исключение
Это обычная маленькая картинка обложки альбома, путь к ней хранить не вариант, так как она вытаскивается из mp3 файла

Какой тип поля в бд использовать?

Comment: Вопрос напонает вот этот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/72679/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-picture/419496#419496

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для хранения картинки Вам нужен тип данных `varbinary(MAX)`. Далее преобразуете картинку в массив байтов и этот массив записываете в БД.

---

Что бы сохранить картинку в БД, делаем следующее:

1) Преобразуем изображение в массив байт:

`var data = File.ReadAllBytes("путь к картинке");`

2) Массив байт в картинку.

```
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data))
{
      using(var img = Image.FromStream(ms)) 
      {
      }
}
```

P.S. Так же вам в БД может пригодится поле, в котором указан `MimeType`, он зависит от конкретного расширения картинки его можно посмотреть в интернете. Поэтому на всякий случай, я бы его завел в БД.

---

Пример для TagLib

1) Получаем картинку

```
TagLib.File tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(mp3FilePath);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(tagFile.Tag.Pictures[0].Data.Data);
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```

2) Получаем массив байт из картинки:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
return  ms.ToArray();
```

3) Аналогично первому примеру, преобразуем массив байт в картинку

```
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data))
{
      using(var img = Image.FromStream(ms)) 
      {
      }
}
```

Comment: А можно пример преобразования в массив байтов и обратно?

Иии картинка выдёргивается из мп3 в формате IPicture, этот тип предусмотрен библиотекой TagLib

Comment: Обновил ответ..